# Rails field values not recovered correctly the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm having a little problem with my rails app, I've created a cascade city selection system, we first select the country and then I make an internal call to receive the state json of the states linked to the country and then once the state is selected, I do the same for the city, everything works fine except for a small bug.

When I load the page for the first time, I can change the city and it saves properly. on the other hand if I change country, state and city, then the country is safeguarded as it should be, the state too but not the city. when the page and returned after saving the city and is always the 1st of the list and it is only at this moment that if I change only the city it is saved well.

On the ruby side, I put a byebug in a before_update and I noticed that in the first case the one where the city is badly saved, it's the index of the city that I receive and not the full name of the city, whereas in the other case when it saves itself properly it's the name of the city that I get.

side js I recover the value of the dropdown in an onchange event that I send in console, and in any case it is the name of the city that appears.

person_settings.js

```
// This is executed when contry_select is changed
$('#person_country_of_birth').on('change', function(event) {
  var stateInput = $("#person_state_of_birth");
  var country_code = $('#person_country_of_birth :selected').val();
  var sendDatas = { "country_code": country_code };

  getDatas(sendDatas, stateInput, "update_states");
});

// This is executed when state_select is changed
$('#person_state_of_birth').on('change', function(event) {
  var cityInput = $("#person_city_of_birth");
  var country_code = $('#person_country_of_birth :selected').val();
  var state_code = $('#person_state_of_birth :selected').val();
  var sendDatas = { "country_code": country_code, "state_code": state_code};

  getDatas(sendDatas, cityInput, "update_cities");
});

// Check value when change (test)
$('#person_city_of_birth').on('change', function(e) {
  console.log(this.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text)
  // $('#person_city_of_birth').text(this.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text);
});

// This function send selected data to get cascading response
function getDatas(sendDatas, inputTarget, urlAction){
  var url = window.location.origin + "/dynamic_select/"
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url + urlAction,
    dataType: "json",
    data: sendDatas,
    success: function(response){
        if(getType(response) == "[object Array]"){
          console.log(response)
          console.log(sendDatas)
          appendStateData(response, inputTarget);
        }
        else if(getType(response) == "[object Object]"){
          appendCityData(response, inputTarget);
        }
    },
    error: function(resp) {
      alert(resp)
      console.log(resp)
    }        
  });
};

// Append states datas on state_select
function appendStateData(datas, state_input){
  state_input.empty();
  $.each(datas, function(index, value) {
    state_input.append("<option value="+index+">"+value+"</option>");
  }); 
};

// Append cities datas on city_select
function appendCityData(datas, city_input){
  city_input.empty();
  $.each(datas, function(index, value) {
    city_input.append("<option value="+index+">"+value+"</option>");
  }); 
};

// This function check the type of response
// State datas is an object
// City datas is an array
function getType( obj ){
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).toString();
};
```

contact.haml

```
.row
  .col-6
    .inline-label-container
      = form.label :spoken_languages, @spoken_languages_title
    %span.alert-box-icon
      = icon_tag("information", ["icon-fix"])
    %small
      = t("settings.profile.spoken_languages_description")
    = form.select(:spoken_languages, @spoken_languages_datas.each { |p| [p] }, {prompt: 'Select a language'}, {multiple: true, size: @spoken_languages_datas.count, style: 'height: 180px;'})

  .col-3
    = form.label :birth_date, t("settings.profile.birth_date")
    = form.date_field :birth_date, :class => "date_field", :maxlength => "10", paceholder: "30/12/2018", style: "height: 40px; width: 250px;"
  .col-3
    = form.label :nationality, t("settings.profile.nationality")
    = form.select(:nationality, @nationality_datas)
  .col-3
    = form.label :country_of_birth, t("settings.profile.country_of_birth")
    = form.country_select :country_of_birth, priority_countries: eu_countries_codes, include_blank: false
  .col-3
    = form.label :state_of_birth, t("settings.profile.state_of_birth")
    = form.select(:state_of_birth, CS.states(target_user.country_of_birth).each { |sym, state| [sym, state]}.to_a.map {|arr| arr.reverse!})
  .col-6
    = form.label :city_of_birth, t("settings.profile.city_of_birth")
    = form.select(:city_of_birth, CS.cities(target_user.state_of_birth, target_user.country_of_birth))
```

Answer (score 0):

It solved, the problem came from the fact that for cities it was an array and not a hash that I received from the hit the index was used as a value, I added a javascript method that does the conversion for me after I received the answer and everything works.

```
// This function covert array into object 
// and set keys == value ex : {lisboa: "lisboa"}
function toObject(arr) {
  console.log(arr)
  var rv = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
    rv[arr[i]] = arr[i];
  console.log(rv)
  return rv;
}
```